# Call PHP interpreter and give it POST data

Tags: php, c++, webserver

I'm developing a little web server in C++, now I'm trying to implement PHP support for my WS, or better I'm trying to figure out how to implement that.
But I've got some doubts: for now I have the client's request in a std::string, if it's a static request there's no problem: let's find file and put in on socket buffer; if it's a dynamic request(PHP only for now), of course I will need to call the interpreter(std::system() ??).
Now my mainly doubt is about forms, I get my POST request and I save form fields in a string, but now: How can I fill $_POST used in my php script and call the interpreter? I could put my fields string as argv by "php -f file.php "fields string" but ,of course, it's awful.

Comment: You just need the `php-cgi` binary, set up some (a lot) environment variables, and push the POST request body as stdin to the interpreter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a webserver interface with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056697/how-does-a-webserver-interface-with-php)

Comment: Thank you very much, but how can i put POST request body as php://stdin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the POST body, you basically pipe it in

```
  echo "$POST_BODY" | php-cgi
```

For C and C++ you don't want to use just `popen()`, but also capture the output and stderr. So you need something like: [how to control popen stdin, stdout, stderr redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280571/how-to-control-popen-stdin-stdout-stderr-redirection)