# Can't pass $_POST values to php-cgi

Tags: php, cgi, webserver

I'm trying to develop a web server with PHP support so I'm doing some little tests with php-cgi, but I can't pass to the interpreter $_POST values.
I've already read this topics, but I couldn't do anything :(:

- [Call PHP from virtual/custom "web server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047426/call-php-from-virtual-custom-web-server)
- [How to pass POST data to the PHP-CGI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030147/how-to-pass-post-data-to-the-php-cgi)

My source:

```
export GATEWAY_INTERFACE="CGI/1.1"
export SCRIPT_FILENAME="/home/xzhttpd/htdocs/test.php"
export REQUEST_METHOD="POST"
export REDIRECT_STATUS=200
export SERVER_PROTOCOL="HTTP/1.1"
export REMOTE_HOST="127.0.0.1"
export CONTENT_LENGHT=3
export HTTP_ACCEPT="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
export CONTENT_TYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
export BODY="t=1"

exec echo "$BODY" | /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

I got this:

> PHP Notice: Undefined index: t in /home/xzhttpd/htdocs/test.php on line 1

PHP source:

```
<?php print $_POST["t"]; ?>
```

Comment: useful comment, congratulations, I managed to resolve my problem thanks to you

Comment: The error is a php error yet you posted no code for php...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass POST data to the PHP-CGI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030147/how-to-pass-post-data-to-the-php-cgi)

Comment: @user665766 you ask for free help, you shouldn't be so rudely sarcastic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `CONTENT_LENGHT` misspelled.

It should be `CONTENT_LENGTH`

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a few more crucial CGI environment variables (it's best to set [**all** of them](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/cgi_env.shtml)), which when absent make PHP ignore the request and POST body:

```
export SCRIPT_NAME="xy.php"
export REQUEST_URI="/xy.php"
export SERVER_NAME="example.com"
export SERVER_PROTOCOL="HTTP/1.1"
```

That will lead to another PHP warning due to [`REDIRECT_STATUS=`](http://php.net/security.cgi-bin). (Don't remember how that works, probably requires more `REDIRECT_*` aliases, but one could just disable `force-cgi-redirect` in the php.ini for testing.)