# Setting $_POST for filter_input_array(INPUT_POST) in phpunit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, http-post, global

Having some issues using PHPUnit to test my controllers.

Code I was working on so far was implementing `$_POST` or other request variables:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST';
$_POST = array(
    'test' => true
);
```

Most of tests worked perfectly this way until I run into methods that take uses of `filter_input_array` function:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST';
$_REQUEST = $_POST = $GLOBALS['_POST'] = array(
    'test' => true
);

// ....

var_dump(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST));
```

> NULL

I'm not willing to remove `filter_input` functions from not mine code, but I'm unable to make them working in tests.

> Versionings:
> PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9 (cli) (built: Apr 17 2015 11:44:57) 
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
> PHPUnit 4.6.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Any help will be appreciated.

## EDIT 2015.05.11

Setting `$_SERVER` with `CONTENT_LENGTH` and `CONTENT_TYPE` does not fix the problem. My version of PHP does not allow me to write to `php://stdin` in way its described in PHP 5.6.0 chagelog (or way I understand it), but `file_put_contents(STDIN,..)` succeed but does not work anyway.

Because it is a phpunit test, maybe there is some kind of annotation or `phpunit.xml` entry I don't know yet, that may fix this problem in [php-cgi POST setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030147/how-to-pass-post-data-to-the-php-cgi) manner.

Comment: Your two examples assign `$_POST` differently. What are the values of the three variables `$_REQUEST`, `$_POST` and `$GLOBALS['_POST']` *before* you do `$_REQUEST = $_POST = $GLOBALS['_POST']`?

Comment: Their empty arrays. As it is a phpunit test, it runs in command line (php-cli) so it is not even going though web server and no `$_REQUEST`-related vars should be set anyway. I was looking at unit tests of php itself, how they test `filter_input_array` but it did not helped me at all.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655284/how-to-pass-parameters-from-command-line-to-post-in-php-script it may help ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the input to `filter_input_array` can only be set by the initial request, and not changed at run time, then the only way to still test it is to have a your base test proxy to another test script by making an HTTP request with the right POST data and processing the response.

main_test.php:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'testname' => 'yourtestname',
    'some_post_var' => 'some_value'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/proxy_test.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if ($response == 'pass') {
  // test passed
}
```

proxy_test.php

```
<?php
$test_name $_POST['testname']; // what test to run?
$response = run_test($test_name); // run test that uses filter_input_array
if ($response) {
    echo "pass"; // used by main_test.php to check if test passed
} else {
   echo "fail";
}
```

Comment: Thumbs up for suggesting `curl`. It's  workaround, but does seem to work. Also, can you edit your proxy_test( `$test_name =`) ?

Comment: Looks like a way to do this. Will try. Unfortunately it probably won't provide code coverage in configuration I have curretly, but for now can live w/o that.

Answer (score 7):

It seems like this is a limitation of PHP, `filter_input_array()` does not allow a `$_POST` array modified at runtime. See [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42608) for some more information. The workaround is probably to use one of [the other filter functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php) and pass in the `$_POST` array yourself.

Comment: Seems like providen bug still exists, as function is returning NULL instead of false or empty array. Anyway, I think that it may be possible to run this test in phpunit, as this tool provides running scripts in separate processes, and I provided an SO answer that proofs that setting POST on script startup is possible. I just have not found a workaround for my case.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the arguments is set, this function returns `NULL`, `not an array of NULL values.`

// No POST vars set in request

```
$_POST = array();
$args = array('some_post_var' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$myinputs = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $args);
var_dump($myinputs);

Expected Output: array(1) { ["some_post_var"]=> NULL }
```

> Actual Output: NULL

While filtering input arrays, be careful of what flags you set besides `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY`. For example, setting the flags like so:

```
 <?php 
    $filter = array( 
    'myInputArr' => array('filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, 
                          'flags' => array('FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW', 'FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY')) 
    ); 

$form_inputs = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filter); 
?>
```

> .. will result in a blank $form_inputs['myInputArr'] regardless of
>   what $_POST['myInputArr'] contains.

Comment: Sorry if I can't follow, but how is this helping me with my question?

Answer (score 1):

One approach to this is to use a helper method to run your `filter_input_array` inside of then mock this method during tests to use something else like `filter_var_array`.

For example this use case could be accomplished by doing:

```
class Data_Class {

    protected function i_use_filters() {
        return $this->filter_input_array();
    }


    protected function filter_input_array() {
        return filter_input_array( INPUT_POST );
    }
}

class Test_Class extends TestCase {

    public function test_filters() : void {
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder( Data_Class::class )
                     ->setMethods( [ 'filter_input_array' ] )
                     ->getMock();
        $mock->method( 'filter_input_array' )
             ->willReturnCallback( function () {
                 if ( ! isset( $_POST ) ) {
                     return null;
                 }
                 return \filter_var_array( $_POST );
             } );

        $_POST['test'] = true;
        $this->assertTrue( $mock->i_use_filters()['test'] );
    }
}
```